# If $x:[0,\infty)$ is càdlàg, then the left-limit function $x^-(t):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$ has right-limits equal to $x(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ be càdlàg and $$x^\pm(t):=x(t\pm):=\lim_{s\to t\pm}x(s)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0,$$ where $x(0-):=x(0)$,.

> How can we show that $x^-(t+)=x(t)$ for all $t\ge0$?

I really got trouble to wrap my head around this. Let $t>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $x$ is right-continuous at $t$, there is a $\delta_+>0$ with $$\forall u\in(t,t+\delta_+):d(x(t),x(u))<\varepsilon.\tag1$$ And since $x$ has a left-limit at $t$, there is a $\delta_-\in(0,t)$ with $$\forall s\in(t-\delta_-,t):d(x(s),x(t))<\varepsilon\tag2.$$ But what we need is a $\delta>0$ with $$\forall u\in(t,t+\delta):d(x^-(s),x(t))<\varepsilon\tag3.$$ How can we show this?

Comment: What do you mean by $x^-(t+)$? This doesn't match any of your definitions

Comment: What language is *càdlàg* and what does it mean? Is $E$ complete?

Comment: @TedShifrin  I have never seen it either.  But voilà: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Holy cow! I am relatively fluent in French and have never seen this before.

Comment: @TedShifrin   They are simply regulated functions that are right-continuous.  Who knew they deserved a new name.  *La Vache!* indeed.

Comment: @TedShifrin ... **càdlàg** is not a *French* term, it is a *mathematics* term.  I imagine few French speakers who are not mathematicians have heard of it.  And many mathematicians who speak no French *have* heard of it.

Comment: @GEdgar: I understand that. In my 50 years as a mathematician and more of speaking French, I've never encountered it. Clearly it shows up only in a very narrow band of mathematical discourse.

Comment: @Snaw: Note that $x^-: [0,\infty)\rightarrow E$ is a function. Therefore, $x^-(t+)$ denotes the right-hand limit $\lim_{s\rightarrow t+} x^-(s)$. We need to show that it exists and equals to $x(t)$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thanks.

Comment: @TedShifrin it is standard notation throughout probability and stochastic analysis. Anyone familiar with the basics of the general theory of Markov processes on reasonable (say Polish) spaces in continuous time will have seen the term.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the proof is elementary and just plays with definition.

Let $t_{0}\geq0$ be fixed. Denote $x(t_{0})=L$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be arbitrary. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $d(x(t),L)<\varepsilon$
whenever $t\in[t_{0},t_{0}+\delta)$. This is possible because $x$
is right-continuous.

Let $t\in(t_{0},t_{0}+\delta)$ be arbitrary. By the definition of
left-limit $x^{-}$, there exists $s\in(t_{0},t)$ such that $d\left(x^{-}(t),x(s)\right)<\varepsilon$.
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & d\left(x^{-}(t),L\right)\\
 & \leq & d\left(x^{-}(t),x(s)\right)+d\left(x(s),L\right)\\
 & < & 2\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
by observing that $s\in(t_{0},t)\subseteq[t_{0},t_{0}+\delta)$. Therefore $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}+}x^{-}(t)=x(t_{0})$.